# How to create a custom loss function in Pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, loss-function

I’m trying to train a network by my own loss function.
I can train a network with loss functions are included in the PyTorch.

But, I meet the challenge when I am trying to define my own loss function.
Indeed, I need to a correct example to train a network by custom loss function in details

My loss function is:

[image]

Comment: How is your loss function defined?

Comment: Any node in the computational graph supports the `.backward` method and hence can serve as a loss function. You just need to compute that value `loss = ...` and then call `loss.backward`. Loss is always minimized.

Comment: The reference seems to be taken from here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.03135.pdf